# DTO Query with JPA CriteriaQuery and Hibernate using entity as a DTO constructor creates many selects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

**hibernate 5.2.10.Final**

**jpa 2.1**

I want to map a projection query to a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with JPA Criteria Query and Hibernate. I specify a constructor that will be applied to the results of the query execution.

If the constructor is for entire entity class, I have multiple of selects instead one(it is a long running process for thousands of records). If the constructor is for a set of params of the Entity then I see only one select in the console. I can't understand where I've mistaken or is it a bug?

```
public class ServiceDAO {

      public List<ServicesDTO> getAllServicesByFilter(ServicesFilter filter) {

          CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<ServicesDTO> criteria = cb.createQuery(ServicesDTO.class);
          Root<ServicesEntity> serviceEntity = criteria.from(ServicesEntity.class);

          // here is only one select to get list of services    
          criteria.select(cb.construct(ServicesDTO.class, serviceEntity.get("active"), serviceEntity.get("providerId"), serviceEntity.get("serviceId")));

          // in this case I have multiple selects
          //criteria.select(cb.construct(ServicesDTO.class, serviceEntity)); 
          if(filter != null) {
             List<Predicate> pcl = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

             if(filter.getActive() != null)
                pcl.add(cb.equal(serviceEntity.get("active"), filter.getActive()));
             if(filter.getProviderId() != null)
                pcl.add(cb.equal(serviceEntity.get("providerId"), filter.getProviderId()));
             if(filter.getServiceId() != null)
                pcl.add(cb.equal(serviceEntity.get("serviceId"), filter.getServiceId()));

             criteria.where(pcl.toArray(new Predicate[pcl.size()]));
          }

          return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
      }

}
```

-

```
public class ServicesDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Boolean active;
    private Integer providerId;
    private Integer serviceId;

    public ServicesDTO() {}

    public ServicesDTO(Boolean active, String providerId, Integer serviceId) {

         this.active = active;
         this.providerId = Integer.parseInt(providerId);
         this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }


    public ServicesDTO(ServicesEntity service) {

       if(service != null) {
           this.active = service.isActive();
           this.providerId = Integer.parseInt(service.getProviderId());
           this.serviceId = service.getServiceId();
       }

    // getters & setters

}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ServicesEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "serviceId", nullable = false)
   private int serviceId;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String providerId;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
   private Categories categoryId;

   private boolean active;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "service", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Service_Area_Ref> areas = new ArrayList<Service_Area_Ref>();

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
   @JoinColumn(name="parentCatId")
   private Categories parentCatId;

   public ServicesEntity() {}

   public ServicesEntity(int serviceId) {
       this.serviceId = serviceId;
   }

   // getters & setters

   // equals & hashcode

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, so it does. There is probably not much of a use case for that. Given

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer value;

public class ADto {
    private Integer va;

    public ADto(A a) {
        this.va = a.getValue();
    }
    public ADto(Integer va) {
        this.va = va;
    }
```

Then

```
tx.begin();

A a1 = new A();
a1.setValue(1);
A a2 = new A();
a1.setValue(2);
em.persist(a1);
em.persist(a2);

tx.commit();

em.clear();

System.out.println("As usual");
em.createQuery("select new dto.ADto(a.value) from A a where a.value <= 2", ADto.class).getResultList();

System.out.println("As A");
em.createQuery("select new dto.ADto(a) from A a where a.value <= 2", ADto.class).getResultList();
```

gives you

```
create table A (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), value integer, primary key (id))
create table B (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), value integer, primary key (id))
insert into A (id, value) values (default, ?)
insert into A (id, value) values (default, ?)
As usual
select a0_.value as col_0_0_ from A a0_ where a0_.value<=2
As A
select a0_.id as col_0_0_ from A a0_ where a0_.value<=2
select a0_.id as id1_0_0_, a0_.value as value2_0_0_ from A a0_ where a0_.id=?
select a0_.id as id1_0_0_, a0_.value as value2_0_0_ from A a0_ where a0_.id=?
```

And you don't like the fact that entity A is selected each time for a new ADto instance. It's probably done that way because you could have created a DTO with multiple entities, not just A, like A, B, and C and so how would JPA/Hibernate do that conveniently in a single select statement? While it could select all the attributes and then keep track of which attributes belong to which entities and then construct them and pass them to your DTO so you can deconstruct them that seems like a lot of work for a rare thing. It's probably more efficient and better all around if you select the attributes you want and make a constructor out of whatever that is, as in the first case.

Comment: ok, thanks, it's not so easy to understand for the first time. I thought it's equivalent of "select * from Table..." query where I select all attributes of the Table and i have not to make a constructor for all attributes(e.g. it could be tens of them and every time I must to fill the criteria's constructor by these attributes and control it if the Entity would be ever changed).

Comment: But I can't understand why was the problem for Hibernate to get all the attributes in first query and then to make second query to get list of the Entity with all attributes instead of thousands single select statements. It really slow down the system, but from the other side I have to point tens of attributes and control the Entity for changes and to expand the constructor if new attribute will be added (or possible deleted). Does it impossible to make a dynamic query (maybe not using criteria) like "select * from Table..."?

Comment: Understood and I don't know of any good solution for that other than unit testing, documentation and use of patterns, which you are doing with DTOs. Those helps to show what areas a change in the database schema affects.SQL is very disconnected from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hibernate 5.3 and also encounter this behaviour. But I found that if using JPA `Tuple` as a DTO container and `multiselect`, this problem will not happen. So my final solution is use `Tuple` to query the result set first and then convert it to DTO manually , something likes:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = cb.createTupleQuery();

.......

criteria.multiselect(serviceEntity);

List<ServicesDTO>  result = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList().stream()
.map(t->new ServicesDTO(t.get(0,ServicesEntity.class)))
.collect(toList());
```